# JWTParser - NoSuchMethodError - ObjectMapper.readerFor

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jwt

I'm getting the below error while trying to create JWTVerifier object in order to decode the token. Can you please help me understand what could be the root cause? Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;
at com.auth0.jwt.impl.JWTParser.<init>(JWTParser.java:25)
at com.auth0.jwt.impl.JWTParser.<init>(JWTParser.java:20)
at com.auth0.jwt.JWTDecoder.<init>(JWTDecoder.java:27)
at com.auth0.jwt.JWT.decode(JWT.java:45)
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question - which library do you use and how do you build your program. It seems like you have a collision between your `java-jwt` transitive dependency and your actual jackson dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, you are using the wrong jackson-databind library version. The error you see appears, when you have a library containing a class but the class is missing a method. Why? Well, probably the method is not in the version you are using or has been deprecated and removed.

Please check your maven/gradle/whatever you are using and play with the version definition a bit. If this does not help, see the output of `mvn dependency:tree` or similar in the build tool of your choice.

Comment: Hi Marek , thanks for your reply. I've updated jackson-databind library version and it works fine.